# How to compile a C program that uses math.h?

Tags: compiling, gcc, c

I am having problems in math.h header file and when I use square root function as in `sqrt(d)`. But my compiler is not supporting this. Please advise me about this problem.

My Ubuntu version is 2012.

Comment: Whilst we love programming questions - the question must be related to Ubuntu - can you clarify in detail what the issue is here - examples etc?

Comment: it is like sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))... my compiler is not supporting this command

Comment: please respond by editing your question.  Give code examples, how you are compiling, version of ubuntu, version of the compiler, have you tried to do this on another compiler/distro.  What happens etc?

Comment: @shreya Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033898/why-do-you-have-to-link-the-math-library-in-cu

Comment: I really don't think this is off-topic. On many other OSes, like Windows, it is unnecessary to pass a special linker option to use the math library in C programs. Even on some Unix-like operating systems the standard C library implementation doesn't require this. This is a problem many users face when they switch to GNU/Linux systems like Ubuntu. I wish the question were better written to include the specific error--if we end up considering this on-topic then perhaps we should edit it--but this is not a general C programming question, it's a question about how to use `gcc` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 46):

*Append `-lm` to the end of your `gcc` command.*

With all recent versions of GCC on GNU/Linux systems like Ubuntu, when you use the math library, you have to explicitly link to it. It is not automatically linked to along with the rest of the standard C library.

If you are compiling on the command-line with the `gcc` or `g++` command, you would accomplish this by [putting `-lm` at the end of the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10059154/1038860).

For example: `gcc -o foo foo.c -lm`

Comment: Thanks for the tip dude!

Answer (score 7):

If you are going to compile a C program with **math.h library** in LINUX using GCC or G++ you will have to use **–lm** option after the compile command.

```
gcc xyz.c -o xyz -lm
```

Here,

**gcc** is compiler command (compiler name)
**xyz.c** is a source file name.
**-o** is an option to specify the output file.
**xyz** is the name of the output file.
**-lm** is an option to link againt the math library (*libm*).

for more details here is the link containing complete article on it. 
***[Compiling C program with math.h in Linux.](http://www.includehelp.com/c-programming-questions/compiling-program-with-math-library-linux.aspx)***

Comment: After the linking command, not the compile command.
(Sorry for the nitpicking, but getting it right helps to understand other situations).

Comment: @mousomer how to get it linking automatically [ubuntu 20.04]